# Get kubernetes apiserver prometheus metrics with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to get kube-apiserver prometheus metrics with `kubectl` command.

I can get it from `kubectl proxy` [**which proxy the api in localhost:8001(by default)**]. then go to `http://localhost:8001/metrics`

I want to get this metrics directly through `kubectl` command, without proxying.

My kubernetes version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.7-gke.24", GitCommit:"2ce02ef1754a457ba464ab87dba9090d90cf0468", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-12T22:05:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer

```
$ kubectl get --raw /metrics
```

This command directly communicate with kube apiserver and get the prometheus metrics of kube apiserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can install helm chart present here -

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator

It will provide you all metrics, you can run the prometheus service locally by port-forwarding and can get all metrics at its dashboard

Comment: is this help me to get prometheus metrics with kubectl command?

Comment: please refer to the README in the link, install the prometheus-operator and then you can locally run the prometheus dashboard in that kubernetes cluster, using kubectl port-forward svc/{prometheus-service-name} , the one which is running at port 9090

Comment: I could get these metrics with `kubectl proxy` > then go to http://localhost:8001. But, I doesn't want to do this. I want to get these metrics direct through kubectl command. like `kubectl get <somethings>`, like some other kubectl command.